# Deleting exact match in file

Tags: php, forms, file, match

I have searched far and wide here but with no solution to my problem (php).

Scenario: User visits a login page with a pre-assigned registration number (in datafile.txt), when entering the number in the field, script searches file if number(s) exists.

If it does exist, goes on to the next step. When the next step has been completed, I would like it to automatically "delete" the number(s) originally used once done.

I believe a "search and replace" is the way to go, while searching for an "exact" match.

My data file would resemble the following: (datafile.txt)

```
0
12
123
1234
12345
123456
```

12, would not be the same as 123 if searched.

A script that I was so kindly given a few days ago is this to accomplish another task:

```
$numbers = file_get_contents("datafile.txt");

$uNumber = $_POST['uNum'];

if ( @preg_match( "/([^0-9]{$uNumber}[^0-9])/", $numbers ) ) {

echo "Numbers match";

}
```

What I tried to do for a new task, was the following but with no success:

```
$numbers = file_get_contents('datafile.txt', 'w+');

$uNumber = $_POST['uNum'];

if ( @preg_match( "/([^0-9]{$uNumber}[^0-9])/", $numbers ) ) {

$numbers = preg_replace('.$_Post["uNum"]','',$numbers);

echo "Existed but will be deleted from file. ";


} else {
echo "Message showed if not in file.";
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what you are doing there is just replacing the values of $uNumber. when in fact what you want to do is replace the value of $uNumber and SAVE it as the new content of the file. correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes. Once 1234 (uNum) has been initially entered, I would like it to be deleted from the file afterwards.

Comment: then you should update the file once the number has been deleted. try using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php after the variable has been updated

Comment: I tried file_put_contents($numbers, $uNumber); at the end of OhMrBigshot's code, but it's not working for me. I might have mixed up something.

Comment: it should be file_put_contents(datafile.txt, $numbers);

Comment: I just tried that and it "created" a new file called "datafiletxt" with no "dot" and the server is not letting me delete the file.

Comment: you would have an easier time using a database. Store the keys in one table, select from that table and if found delete the row. Using a file to do this is not very efficient, for several reasons you might not be interested in right now. Just use a table

Comment: @Pablo I would if I could, believe me, but I know nothing about them (SQL etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one:

```
$index = file_get_contents("datafile.txt"); 
$bodycont = str_replace("string to be replaced","what you want that string to be",$index);
$fh = fopen("datafile.txt","w");
fwrite($fh,$bodycont);
fclose($fh);
```

OR:

```
 $file = file("datafile.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
 foreach($file as $text) {
 $test[] = $text;
 }

//get the size of the array

$arraysize = sizeof($test);

//use for loop to check if that string is found in the array and replace it

for($x=0;$x<$arraysize;$x++)
    {
               if($test[$x] == "$uNumber")
                {

                }
                else
                {
                   $newarray[] = $test[$x];
                }
    }
 $stringData = implode("\n",$newarray );
 $fh = fopen("datafile.txt","w");
 fwrite($fh,$stringData );
 fclose($fh);
```

this should somehow work. :D

Comment: Thanks. Am toying with it now. I tested with the number 1234 which is in the file and replaced it with 1212, yet 123456 also exists in the file and that was changed by the script to 121256. I need an exact match. I'll keep at it till I get it. LOL

Comment: then all you need to do is change str_replace or use a better condition. hope this help. feel free to up it or check it. thanks :)

Comment: Tried preg_match( "/^({$uNum})$/", $index); and "uNumber" but it's writing a 0 (zero) in its place and not appending to the file even with "a, a+, w+). I know a database would be the way to go, but I know nothing about SQL etc.

Comment: you should not use append, since the word append means adding when what you are doing is removing or replacing. try using the second one. and dont use pregmatch. since the best way to accomplish this is a) put the string in an array and loop trough it to remove the said data, or b) use sql.

Comment: Your new code is giving me Internal Server Error. Seems there's a { not closing somewhere from what I could tell.

Comment: @FredFletcher sorry about that, missed a semicolon and an array tag. edited it now.

Comment: No harm done ;-) Now, it worked but it saved the file as DOC_ROOTdatafile.txt and didn't delete the numbers I typed in (1234), probably because it didn't open the original datafile.txt file.

Comment: @FredFletcher sorry again, forgot to remove DOC_ROOT. edited the file.

Comment: Not a problem. I deleted it myself, yet it's not working. What it did, was it deleted the empty line I have at the end of the file, but did not delete the numbers 1234.

Comment: UPDATE great news, I used some of your code and came up with this $bodycont = preg_replace("/\b({$_POST['inscripnum1']})\b/","",$index); works great, except that where the number used to be, there is a blank line. Any way I can delete that at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a one number per line file, use `^` and `$` to limit your regex to match the exact pattern.

```
preg_match( "/^({$uNumber})$/", $numbers)
```

Comment: Thanks Boris. Is the rest of my code ok (the 2nd part) of my message, or do I need to modify something else?

Answer (score 0):

Why use Regex for something so simple? You can just go like this:

```
<?php
$numbers = file_get_contents("datafile.txt");
$uNumber = $_POST['uNum'];

$numbers = explode($numbers, "\n");

foreach ($numbers as $num) {
     if ($num == $uNumber) {
         unset($num);
     }
}

$numbers = implode($numbers, "\n");

// some code that saves the file
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Couldn't I just use $numbers = file_get_contents("datafile.txt", "a"); to write the new content to file, or how would I go about it?

Comment: I think you want to use file_put_contents: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: I tried file_put_contents($numbers, $uNumber); but it's not working for me. Might have something mixed up.

Comment: If you want to just append to the file, use the `F_APPEND` flag, otherwise the file is re-written. Make sure you write the correct var too, from the looks of your code I'd say you want to re-write `$numbers` as the file, or append `$uNumber`

Comment: I just found the FILE_APPEND stateent, added it but any which way, the file is not getting written to, nor overwritten. Stumped.